# jquery Infinite Scroll page number

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using a jQuery plugin called InfiniteScroll (https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll) and I have a URL with this pattern: `'/category/2/'`, when I paged the result I use the following pattern: `"/category/2?page=2"`.

When Infinite Scroll makes de request, he increments the wrong number, in the case above, the request is: `"/category/3?page=2"` in place of `"/category/2?page=3"`.

Anyone knows how workaround this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a custom `pathParse` option -

```
pathParse:function(path,nextPage){
   path = path.match(/category\/[0-9]*\?page=([0-9]*)/).slice(1);
   return path;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using http://pengkong.github.io/jquery-auto-pagination/ it doesn't depend on the next page link format, running page numbers and/or fixed increments.